# Why my bootstrap toggle is not change while function at JS has been set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, toggle

I want to make the toggle change either On or Off depending what had been set in JS. In this case I set to Inactive in `JS` as my `HTML` is using Active/Inactive value when the Modal is closed. As shown in example my dropdown  below is working well, it change the value to Standard once the Modal is closed.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-4">Status Device</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_pump">
            <div class="slider round">
                <span class="on" name="add_device_status" id="add_device_status" value="Active" autocomplete="off">ON</span>
                <span class="off" name="add_device_status" id="add_device_status" value="Inactive" autocomplete="off">OFF</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-4">Device Rule</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="add_device_rule" class="custom-select form-control">
                <option value="std_pckg">Standard Package</option>
                <option value="vip_pckg">VIP Package</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#add_new_device_modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $('#add_device_status').val("Inactive");
    $('#add_device_rule').val("std_pckg");
});
```

Comment: you have multiple same id´s, so youre setting .val() of span element which seems not so plausible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/w0aqvg5m/

use checked property to toggle in modal hidden event

`$('#toggle_pump').prop('checked',true)`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you declared 2 ID with same name in that portion.

```
<div class="slider round">
<span class="on" name="add_device_status" id="add_device_status" 
value="Active" autocomplete="off">ON</span>
<span class="off" name="add_device_status" id="add_device_status" 
value="Inactive" autocomplete="off">OFF</span>
</div>
```

Change it to -

```
<div class="slider round">
<span class="off" name="add_device_status" id="add_device_status" 
value="Active" autocomplete="off">ON</span>
</div>
```

JS-

```
$("#add_new_device_modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
$('#add_device_status').val("Inactive");
$('#add_device_status').innerHTML = "OFF";
$('#add_device_rule').val("std_pckg");
});
```